# Fast way to generate token - PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string)

i want to generate random token [alphanumeric] for random length [between 4-6] characters.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: more in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=random+string+php

Comment: no, they use HASHING, i need a small one, so why should i waste CPU ?

Comment: The question also has an answer with pseudocode that implements what you wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you can just get a random number between 10+26+26=62 6 times, and then calculate the resulted string, this seems easy enough.

```
<?php
function ()
{
$letters={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
return array_rand($letters).array_rand($letters)......... // you get the point

?>
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/function.uniqid.php) (search for "token" in the examples given there) and shorten it with [substr](http://php.net/manual/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 2):

or if you prefer the 'hard' way...

```
$len = random(4,6);
$token = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
  $ord = 0;
  switch(random(1,3)) {
    case 1: // 0 - 9
      $ord = random(48,57);
      break;
    case 2: // A - Z
      $ord = random(65,90);
      break;
    case 3: // a - z
      $ord = random(97,112);
      break;
  }
  $token[] = chr($ord);
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't be really random, much higher chances of getting an '3' then on 'O'... see my method for a better solution

Comment: I was about to give that as well, but I'm too lazy to write all those alphanumeric chars. anyway, how can you say that the chance of getting '3' is higher?

Comment: cause, to get '3' you have 1-3 choice, and then 1-10, total 1/30 to get 'O' you have 1-3 choice, and then 1-26, total 1/78. therefore, this method isn't good enough...

Comment: I see, the randomness isn't uniformly distributed...