# How to generate unique numbers/IDs without duplicates?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string)

I wish to generate Product Keys or Licenses using PHP. Is there a function that allow me to do generate unique numbers/IDs but at the same time make sure that there won't be a chance for duplicate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use php's uniqid function to generate id's:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

or leave that responsibility to the database engine, which will generate auto-incremented id values.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `md5(timestamp)`, its always unique

Comment: unless 2 calls are made at the exact same time!

Comment: exactly as @BenRowe mentioned: If you generate multiple keys during one PHP call this will definitely end with duplicates