# Stop duplication of random string during PHP session

Tags: php, random, session-variables

I am using the following PHP to generate a few (usually 3) random strings and place them in session variables to use as controls.

```
function session_var($type) {
if ( !isset ( $_SESSION[$type] ) ) {
$_SESSION[$type] = rand_string( 5 );
}
}

function rand_string( $length ) {
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";    
$size = strlen( $chars );
$str = '';
for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
$str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
}
return ($str);
}
```

How do I eliminate the rare occasion where the same random string might be generated more than once in the same session? I don’t want any of the session variables to be the same.

Thanks

Comment: Use `uniqid()` instead of generating your own... http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php (assuming having numerals in there isn't a problem)

Comment: The lazy and rubbish approach is to `in_array()` and generate the string again if it is duplicated, but I'm sure someone has a better approach than that so this is not going to be an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simply rely on a good algorithm for random identifiers generation (especially if you expect the number of such session variables to grow with time and so you need a scalable solution); there are UUID generation algorithm that are guaranteed to have a barely appreciable probability to generate the same uuid twice in the entire lifetime of the solar system.

Try to have a glance on this: http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid

Theory about UUIDs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Version_4_.28random.29

Answer (score 0):

How about something really simple like:

> $rand = microtime(true).rand()?