# Phone Number Verification

Tags: android, string

I have been trying to implement a sort of One-Time phone number verification system in my android app.

I researched and discovered that outfits like twilio were offering this service, but they are all expensive to use. All i want is just a Random, Unique code that would be sent to the phone number the user supplied.

So searched some more and found [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1846202/583513), which talks about generating unique, random alphanumeric Strings using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bits). But i don't know the way forward from here.

My Problems

1. After generating the Strings and saving them in the database. How do i send one to the user's phone number.(I imagine i would need some sort of SMS API).
2. How secure is this method of generating the random strings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a UUID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) on your server and store it in a database. if you're worried about conflicts, check if the generated UUID already exists and if so, generate another one.

In order to send a SMS from Your server, You'll need to use some sort of SMS gateway (such as Twilio)

Comment: Thanks would try that.