# Generate an unique ID to append behind an url

Tags: php, unique-key

I've found [this stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733588/3921478) with the PHP function below and it works perfectly but I don't have enough user reputation to comment on that page and ask for help so that's why I created a new question about this.

Let's say I use the function in my code below to generate a 6 or 8 character key how much chance do I have that this function will generate the same key twice? Is it once every thousand / million / billion times ?

Thank you..

```
function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max) {
        $range = $max - $min;
        if ($range < 0) return $min; // not so random...
        $log = log($range, 2);
        $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
        $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
        $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
        do {
            $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
            $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
        } while ($rnd >= $range);
        return $min + $rnd;
}

function getToken($length){
    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[crypto_rand_secure(0,strlen($codeAlphabet))];
    }
    return $token;
}
```

Comment: That depends on entirely on the min and max values you are using.

Comment: Why re-inventing the wheel when there are several built-in functions to generate unique id's with most probably less collisions... cfr `uniqid()` , `com_create_guid()` , ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is a unique ID, you can just use the `uniqid()` function.

Comment: Thanks, after looking at the uniqid() function I used that. :)