# best way to generate token to validate email account symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, authentication, token

I was just wondering, what would be the best, and the most secure way to generate a token as unique key for a user to validate his account by email address.

I plan to do this this way :

- I am no using FOSUserBundle
- The user register through a form, the user data is save to the database with a "pending" status, and I save also in the database a "key" token to validate the user (do I really need to put this in the database ?).
- The user receive an email with a link to a controller that will check the token/key pass in the link (mysite/validate-account/?key=ljdsak544545asd), I compare it with the value we have in the database, if it matches, the user is validate.

As you can see I know pretty much how to get there I just want to make sure I use the right way to generate a **unique, secure, token as a validation key** in Symfony2.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

see this:

[PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string)

just to be extra safe check the db to see if a duplicate key exists and regenerate until you have a unique one.