# How to generate a random unique string list?

Tags: php

I'm using this function to create a random string, but how would I make it to generate a unique string list for a 500 strings?

```
function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: So you just want an array with 500 random strings?!

Comment: Yes, a random but unique strings.

Comment: So you only want to make sure it is unique? You don't want an array?

Comment: I'm going to store them in a database, so I would have to make sure it's unique.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1846202/3933332

Comment: so generate them in a loop, check if it was already generated, and keep going until you reach 500...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP random string generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)

Comment: how would I store the generated strings into an array_list?

Comment: Be aware that the code above does not produce cryptographically secure random strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worry about inserted rows in table then there are 3 simple ways to do it.

***First way,*** you can check if the string exists in db then create another random string.

***Second way,*** use UUID() function of mysql that generates random value and there's no need to worry about duplication.

***Third way,*** if you want the array, generate 500 string and put in an array. then use array_unique() to remove duplication. If array length was < 500 then generate more (for example 12 strings) then check if < 500 again and again until it reaches exactly 500. Checking can be done in a while loop or so.

```
while( count($arr) < 500 )
{
    $arr[] = generateRandomString();

    if( count($arr) == 500 )
        $arr = array_unique( $arr );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@MohamedFadili You need to first generate your string using `generateRandomString();` then check if it exists in database in that case you need to keep trying till you find one that does not exist, to avoid a dead loop, you can throw an exception after X attempts (X = 10 maybe ?) so the code would look something like below :

a. If you have a unique constraint in your database (it would throw an exception when you insert)

```
$attempts = 10;
$i = 0;
$inserted = false;
while (!$inserted || $i < $attempts) {
try {
    $myRandomString = generateRandomString();
    // MySQL CODE TO DO YOUR INSERT HERE IT COULD THROW AN EXCEPTION IF THE STRING ALREADY EXIST IN DATABASE

    // here if insertion operation was successful you set $inserted variable to true
    $inserted = true;
    } catch (PDOException $ex){
    // do nothing
    }
}
```

b. if no unique index constraint in database, you need to check by your self:

```
$attempts = 10;
$inserted = false;

while (!$inserted || $i < $attempts){
$myRandomString = generateRandomString();

// SQL CODE TO CHECK IF $myRandomString Exist 
// IF NOT EXIST DO INSERT AND SET $inserted to true
$inserted = true;

// ELSE IF EXIST KEEP TRYING

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not generating a list of 500 strings. Clearly, you can accomplish that with a `for` loop:

```
$random = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++)
    $random[] = generateRandomString();
```

What you want is 500 *unique* strings. As @meh points out, you could do this by continually eliminating duplicates with `array_unique`. I'm not a huge fan of doing that on every pass, though, as it results in generating a new, unique array at minimum 500 times! What I would prefer to do would be to check prior to the insertion of each value into the array that it isn't a duplicate. A search is faster than a search and removal which in turn is faster than an n² search and removal. Something like this, perhaps:

```
$unique = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++)
{
    do
    {
        $random = generateRandomString();
    } while (in_array($random, $unique));
    $unique[] = $random;
}
```