# PHP - Get an unique ID

Tags: php

I am using php and I want to get a System's UNIQUE ID.
I can't use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` since all machines have the same local IP address (127.0.0.1). Is there anything else I could use?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1846202/3933332

Comment: depends on what your call a  "system" there are a number of possible id's depending on usage also

Comment: @Rizier123 i don't believe that is what he is asking

Comment: So what makes a system unique? In what context are you using this? You want to identify the machine some code is running on? What about the system's hostname or a public key generated for each machine? A hash of the ssh hostkey perhaps?

Comment: I'm guessing something along the lines of a mac address

Comment: Something like that Will

Comment: even saying a "computer" really isn't specific enough. please explain the use of this unique ID then we can help you appropriately

Comment: I have a server. When a computer will connect to that server using a software, it will generate a user file. The name for that file used is the computer's REMOTE_ADDR.Sience all REMOTE_ADDRs are 107.0.0.0.1, if more than 1 computer will connect to that server, it will rewrite the file that already exists.

Comment: the software on the remote server should send an id

Comment: I wrote the server myself and it's using wamp as hosting.

Comment: $ipa = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: what protocol is remote computer using to access server?

Comment: if (!(file_exists("Users//" . $ip))){
  
  $my_file = "Users//" . $ipa;
  $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file: '. $my_file);
  $data = 'null';
  fwrite($handle, $data);
  $out = "DONE!";
 }

Comment: It's connecting trough port 80

Comment: IP is not computer\user unique

Comment: I know that's why I want to find a value to replace $ipa

Comment: it's actually connecting to my localhost.That's where the server is hosted, trough port forwarding.

Comment: sorry to many missing details for me.

Answer (score 1):

You won't reliably be able to obtain a MAC address from an end user.  You can't use the hostname because the hostname exposed is based off of the IP address and they are all connecting through the same IP.

The only other way I could think of doing this is using a cookie or authentication.  If they authenticate, then you use their user ID.  If not, then you can set a long term cookie with a uniquely generated ID.  For instance:

```
if (empty($_COOKIE['machine_id'])) {
  $id = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
  setcookie('machine_id', $id, time()+(3*365*86400));
}
```

Then this client would need have a unique identifier for future connections in the machine_id cookie.

This would be dependent on a client enabling cookies and not clearing their cookies.

Comment: im not even clear this is a http connection, and if its not dont expect cookies to be passed. but this could work - if you have 100% control over the remote machine (which if you did there are better ways). but OP is making this to hard to answer - so good luck