# Trying to add random strings in columns whenever new row added

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to populate two columns with random strings whenever a new user is created in laravel

maybe something like this in User model

```
public function putStringInDatabase () {
    $this->public_key = str_random(40);
}
```

and whenever a new row is added in users table public_key and private_key columns get updated automatically by that random string

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events). Specifically `creating`.

For example:

```
User::creating(function($user) {
    $this->public_key = str_random(40);
    $this->private_key = str_random(40);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Try making the string unique!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the controller when you are creating the record

```
/**
 * Create a new Object instance.
 *
 * @param array $data
 *
 * @return Object
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $object = new Object([
        'fields' => $data['values']
        'email' => $data['email'],
    ]);
    $object->public_key = str_random(40);
    $object->save();

    return $object;
}
```

This will let you add a public_key outside of the mass assignment.

Comment: I can do it but I have used this same function in several places throughout my application so to save the time I want something smart which can add the random string in defined column whenever I create a record in database

Comment: Why don't you try to create a helper for that?