# How to autogenerate a random, unique, alphanumeric string as serial number of a product in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, random

I would like to have a string which is unique and which can be autogenerated from the controller to the table directly. How am I to handle that In the controller

I would like to have a $serail_number somewhere that will be unique

```
public function store()
{

    Slaughter::create($this->validateRequest());
    return redirect('/slaughter')->with('message', 'Clinic Details Attached');
}

private function validateRequest()
{ 

    return request()->validate([
        'animal_id' => 'required',
        'slaughter_id' => 'required',
        'slaughtering' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: You could make use of a [Uuid](https://github.com/michaeldyrynda/laravel-efficient-uuid).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a unique random string in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304930/how-can-i-create-a-unique-random-string-in-laravel-5)

Comment: let me try that

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string)

Comment: You can create a random number using PHP's `random_bytes`; however, random numbers cannot ensure absolute uniqueness by themselves. Consider reading my principles on [unique random identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers), and editing your question to respond to the six questions I mention in those principles.

Comment: From Laravel helper functions you may use the UUID https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers

Comment: Is there any way to customize the uuid