# How to generate Randome string from row id(pk) by using base_convert

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table like this

```
----Id----Product----RandomKey--
|   1   |   P1     |  (some key) |
----------------------------------
|   2   |   P2     |  (some key) |
----------------------------------
|   3   |   P3     |  (some key) |
----------------------------------
```

**Here the some key is unique random key**

I want to generate randome string from base_convert. Mean check the previous id suppose 3 and then increment 1 with the value and convert it with using base_convert

```
$rowid=3; //Get the last id from database 
$bnum = base_convert($rowid,36,10);
$rkey = base_convert($bnum+1,10,36);
echo $rkey;
```

Does it always generate randome unique key? I really don't understand **formbase** and **tobase** in **base_convert** syntax

> base_convert(number,frombase,tobase);

Can any one explain me how **frombase** and **tobase** work and by this method can i generate unique key?

**Update:**

If i set

> $rkey = base_convert($bnum+1,10,36);

It will generate flat number, i want number with character. So I changed **36** to **16** mean Hexadecimal like

> $rkey = base_convert($bnum+1,10,16);

and it will produce random string with number and character. If anyone recommend something better please let me know. Thanks

Comment: There are so many questions.. Basicaly - what ist the purpose? Do you just need a short representation of the *Id*? Does it need to be random, and why (what you have tried isn't random at all)?

Comment: I want to create an string it may be 1 digit or more than 1 digit. I want to convert row id to  a unique key(may be 1 or more than 1 digit). If i set 16 to tobase, it will generate alpha numeric character and will look like some random key. I want to create it only because of uniqueness. It will always unique If i am not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can any one explain me how frombase and tobase work and by this method can i generate unique key?

Function [`base_convert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) do not provide generator for unique strings. The purpose of using this function is converting between numeral systems.

Example:

```
$randInt = 10; // we pick up a random integer value
$convertedRandInt = base_convert($randInt, 10, 2); // we converting it

var_dump($convertedRandInt); // output: 00001010
```

In above example, I used this function to convert between decimal numeral system to binary.

```
string base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )
```

Fist parameter is string or number (because chars has their numeric sign, the second is current numeral system of variable (in the example I used decimal) and the third argument is numeral system what we are looking for (in the example, binary).

> If anyone recommend something better please let me know. Thanks

About uniqueness, look at the answers on older topic: [PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string).