# How to know what would be the next auto increment id in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, auto-increment

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
----Id-------Data---
|   1   |   Data1   |
--------------------
|   2   |   Data2   |
--------------------
|   3   |   Data3   |
--------------------
```

If I run this query

> SELECT MAX(id) FROM table

it will show the result **3** and if i increment it with **1** generally this will be the next auto incremented id.

If i delete the record **where id is 3** and after that when i run this query again mean

> SELECT MAX(id) FROM table

it will show **2**, and if i increment it with **1** then it will be **3**. Now if i insert a new record the auto increment id will be **4**.

Now my question is how know what would be the next exact auto increment id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know the next auto incremented value you have to use **information_schema.TABLES** table.

Try this:

```
SELECT T.AUTO_INCREMENT 
FROM information_schema.TABLES T 
WHERE T.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourDBName' 
  AND T.TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName';
```

Comment: @AshisBiswas You're most welcome...

Comment: @AshisBiswas: Yes, but unless you can guarantee that there are no other connections to the database, this value may change before you can use it. This is a bad way of doing things, and if you explain why you think you need to do this then I am sure we can help you with a better way

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this? Answer: you wouldn't.

Comment: @Borodin  I want to use this for [this purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470082/how-to-generate-randome-string-from-row-idpk-by-using-base-convert)

Comment: @AshisBiswas: Okay, well that won't generate a number that is remotely random. In fact, most of the time it will just add one to the row ID. And it is using the *last* row ID and not the *next* one, as you have asked here

Comment: Yes last row id. But if i delete some row the auto increment id would not be changed and it will cause some problem.

Comment: Run this before your query: ANALYZE TABLE `TABLENAME`;

Answer (score 0):

use LAST_INSERTED_ID
as
`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`;

Comment: Thanks for your ans. But i think this is not perfect ans.

Comment: It will work only after insert of record. after deletion of record it won't work

Comment: While it's not a correct answer to the question, it's probably a correct way to solve the problem behind.