# how to generate a 15(alphanumeric) character length unique string for each row inserted in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

I am creating users and saving it in my database table.
I would like to create a column named: haskey, where i store a random and unique 15 digit alphanumeric string for each created user so that it is unique for every user. how do i do this?

Comment: have you tried some code?\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has inbuilt helper function called str_random(). You could use that to generate key.

```
str_random(15)
```

Or I would suggest you to use [laravel hashids.](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids)

### Laravel Hashids

Require this package, with Composer, in the root directory of your project.

```
$ composer require vinkla/hashids
```

Add the service provider to config/app.php in the providers array.

```
Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider::class
```

If you want you can use the facade. Add the reference in config/app.php to your aliases array.

```
'Hashids' => Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids::class
```

### Usage

```
// You can alias this in config/app.php.
use Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids;

Hashids::encode(1);

// We're done here - how easy was that, it just works!
Hashids::decode('doyouthinkthatsairyourebreathingnow');
```

// This example is simple and there are far more methods available.

Comment: thxx @Saravanan Sampathkumar , first method is short and simple with less code..but if i use that i shud still check if string exists in database before inserting right?

Comment: Most of the cases it should be unique. But I suggest you to use hashids. Hashids are unique. Else check and use scott's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string

Answer (score 1):

PHP has rand()

```
function generateRandomNumber($len = 16) {
    $char = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
    $randomNumber = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $randomNumber .= $char[rand(0, $len - 1)];
    }
    return $randomNumber;
}
```

Randomly generated value is unique.

Comment: in this example $numberLength is always going to be 36 right?

Comment: I modified code, can you check , it might meet your requirements

Comment: thank you for that..it looks good..no matter which method i use..i must check my db if the string exist first for double checking right? though the chances are very low to generate a same string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$serial = str_split('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                     .'0123456789');
$haskey = '';
foreach (array_rand($serial, 15) as $a) $haskey.= $serial[$a];
    echo $haskey;
?>
```

Insert the '$haskey' to database. Though it is not guaranteed not to repeat the characters.

Comment: thx for your help very much appreciated..yes if i go with this method i need to double check if such string exist in the database..well i think no matter which method i go with it is still better to check if it exists right

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [UUID Package](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid) which will create ID according to the RFC 4122 standard which will be unique for each user. (Universally Unique)

Step 1 : Require the package according to your laravel version (Below steps are for Laravel 5.*)

```
composer require "webpatser/laravel-uuid:2.*"
```

Step 2 : Edit `config/app.php` and add the alias.

```
'aliases' => [
    'Uuid' => Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid::class,
]
```

Step 3 : Now you can generate UUID as below

```
Uuid::generate()
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this Laravel I'll give you a Laravel solution. You can easily generate a more truly "random" alpha-numeric string using this function:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
$var = Str::random(15);
// $var => "kAQUxlywesTKLrP"
```

Good luck!