# How do i rand string according to index size

Tags: php, string, random, indexing

I don't really know how to go about but it really pretty for me in achievement like each `rand_string` to each index.

My code:

```
function rand_string($length) {
  $str="";
  $chars = "abcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  $size = strlen($chars);
  for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $str .= $chars[rand(0, $size-1)];
  }
  return $str;
}

$pcode = rand_string(4);
for ($b = 0; $b < 3; $b++) {
  echo $pcode[$b];
}
```

I am expecting something like: `9cwm cZnu c9e4` in the output. Can I achieve this in PHP?

Currently, with my code, I get a string from `rand_string` in each index like `9cw`.

Comment: Could you just redact your post(title included) so we could get your intentions more clear? Right now I could only guess that you wanna print  3 random strings... so you should instead of what you are doing now just echo rand_string(4) inside of that second loop.

Comment: You have `a` in `$chars` twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string)

Comment: Updated the formatting and cleaned up some of the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, you only need to call `rand_string` inside your second loop in order to get something like **9cwm cZnu c9e4** (what you have described in your question).

Here is a working example:

```
function rand_string($length) {
    $str="";
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $size = strlen($chars);
    for($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++) {
        $str .= $chars[rand(0,$size-1)];
    }
    return $str;
}

// call rand_string inside for loop
for ($b = 0; $b<3; $b++) {
    echo rand_string(4).' ';
}
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0693c3cb8856781cbef2a6fae5c9c833d81720da)

Comment: in more tips can i get back these string in one line? 
Example:
   `string(12) "9cwmcZnuc9e4"`

Comment: Yes Of course, just do `echo rand_string(4);`  without concatinating ' ' in the last loop

Comment: Geting this string back in one line is in hard size dont seem to be working as expect do a checkup

Comment: Do you want to be like this: [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f6430e7bee33ac7af27bd7add08c245fa629b80) ?

Comment: Yes but in one var_dump string line example:
function rand_string($length) {
        $str="";
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $size = strlen($chars);
        for($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++) {
            $str .= $chars[rand(0,$size-1)];
        }
        return $str;
    }

    // call rand_string inside for loop
    for ($b = 0; $b<3; $b++) {
        $onestringline = rand_string(4);
     var_dump($onestringline);
    }

expecting string( 12) "jd9mjjmdagja"

Comment: You have to use a variable to collect random string and then use var_dump to show it: [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4014418920358f72ba802ebfbdb82bdeff05e0e6)

Comment: Yes very wish never thought big thanks for long time coparation

Answer (score 0):

The generation of the string actually works in your code. You aren't calling/printing the function correctly. Just call the function three times and print all the results (with spaces in between). Instead of printing you could join it together in a string and remove the last space.

```
<?php
function rand_string($length) {
  $str="";
  $chars = "abcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  $size = strlen($chars);
  for($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++) {
   $str .= $chars[rand(0,$size-1)];
  }
  return $str;
 }

  for ($b = 0; $b<3; $b++)
   {
    echo rand_string(4)." ";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using a completely different approach, limited to 32 chars :

```
return substr(md5(mt_rand().time()), 0, $length);
```

It's not *super* random but you get the picture...

Thanks to CM and user2693053 for bringing stuff to my attention (updated answer)

- using `mt_rand()` instead of `rand()`
- `md5()` length of 32...

Comment: i can't detect your method please edit with more codes or idea thanks

Comment: The idea is that you use `md5(rand().time()` to generate a reasonably random string by hashing a combination of a random number and the current time. After that `substr()` is used to return a part of that string with length `$length`. Keep in mind that `md5()` returns a string of 32 characters, so work around that if you can have `$length > 32`.

Comment: `rand()` is not recommended and is an alias for `mt_rand()` in PHP 7. For backwards compatibility reasons you should use `mt_rand()` instead. Hope I helped! -CM

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments ! I will update my answer and credit you ;)