# How do I save texts sent by users via GET input in separate text files in php?

Tags: php

I know how to save the sent texts in 1 text file created beforehand. but I need some way to save each text in separate text files which are created automatically

Comment: Since you know how to write in a file, what stops you from writting in different files ?

Comment: I need the files to be generated automatically and i dont know how to do that.i only know how to write in a file which is created beforehand

Comment: Opening a file for writting/appending will create the file if it doesn't exist. This is stated in the documentation of [`fopen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will save the text, which was provided by the user via GET parameter named `param`, to a new file [with unique name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846229/1719108) in form of hash (something like `6cc50baac239a47e165a320d03c76731.txt`).

```
<?php

$text = $_GET['param'];
file_put_contents(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.txt', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fopen` to create a file, but before using that, read following `PHP Manual` to find which mode is suitable for your case. Have a look in `A list of possible modes for fopen() using mode` section:

[php.net - fopen function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

**Be successful.**