# Will time() ever return the same output?

Tags: php, performance, random, time

I am generating tokens for users in PHP when they register. I am wondering if two users could ever get the same token... as this will break the system. Please let me know if this is suffiecient.

```
$token = md5(rand().time());
```

edit: i am now using a generate_uuid() function i found on another question.
will this work?

```
function generate_uuid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0C2f ) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x2Aff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffD3 ), mt_rand( 0, 0xff4B )
    );

}
```

Comment: Of course it will. `md5` collisions are trivial, it's why it's part of the wikipedia article on md5 hashing over on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities. Good luck. But as a piece of advice: use a uid/uuid library. That's what they're for =)

Comment: Why not use [a UUID](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid)?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string-for-use-in-a-secret-l

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string for use in a secret link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string-for-use-in-a-secret-l)

Comment: i edited the post. can you guys check that out and determine if that will be unique every time??

Comment: Using that function you're generating a UUID from a set of random numbers. In theory, you could generate a set that you've used before, but the chance of this with UUIDs is vanishingly small. If you need to be absolutely certain that a generated UUID is unique in your system, check it and generate another one if necessary. Don't expect to need an extra code often. Or ever.

Answer (score 2):

```
$token = md5(rand().time());
```

Has a good chance of never repeating.

- Time() does repeat within one second.
- Time() repeats for an hour once a year if it is on daylight savings.
- But rand() does not repeat for 2^30 steps.
- MD5 does not increase the randomness, and may even decrease it.

`mt_rand()` is very good at "randomness", but that means that it can *and will* repeat -- at "random" times.  Do *not* trust it for not repeating.

See also `microtime(true)`; it is precise to the microsecond.  But it still can lead to dups, especially if two different clients are using the same formula.

Simply use UUID functions.  They have a lot of research and thought put into them.  You are unnecessarily re-inventing the wheel.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) for why UUIDs mess with *performance* in a database and what to do about it.