# Will this function I made return a unique string EVERY time?

Tags: php, performance, random, mysqli

I have made a function that is supposed to generate a random UUID. It is used for tokens for email verification in my PHP registration script. I need these tokens to be unique everytime or the system will break. As in, there can be no identical outputs.

```
function generate_uuid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0C2f ) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x2Aff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffD3 ), mt_rand( 0, 0xff4B )
    );

}
```

Comment: Don't ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65648350/will-time-ever-return-the-same-output) twice

Comment: it's different code.

Comment: It's the same code as your previous question

Comment: No, do not delete the other question. Asking the same question more than once is not allowed even you delete the other question. Give people a chance to answer

Comment: mt_rand does _not_ guarantee uniqueness.  It _does_ provide good "randomness".