# Should I add a hash to the encrypted cookie to additionally verify the integrity of the data

Tags: php, encryption, cookies

I'm currently working on implementing cookie-based session management in my web application. Up until now, I've set up two methods to encrypt/decrypt the cookie while storing the initialization vector in the cookie itself. `cookieEncryptionKey` returns 32-byte long hash of a key stored externally in a config file.

```
class Auth 
{

    const COOKIE_TTL = 3600;
    const COOKIE_CIPHER = 'aes-256-cbc';

    private function encryptCookie(string $value)
    {
        $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::COOKIE_CIPHER);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_length);
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($value, self::COOKIE_CIPHER, $this->cookieEncryptionKey(), 0, $iv);

        return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
    }

    
    private function decryptCookie(string $value)
    {
        list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($value), 2);

        return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, self::COOKIE_CIPHER, $this->cookieEncryptionKey(), 0, $iv);
    }

}
```

Are there any major security flaws in such implementation?
And should I add extra data integrity checks by including e.g. a hash_hmac signature in the cookie?

My understanding is that it is not necessary because an encrypted message cannot be tampered without knowing the original encryption key.

Comment: PHP does itself have [a cookie based session system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session). Are you reinventing the wheel? Also, what exactly is the initialization vector? Why does it need to be encrypted? That's not how normal session cookies work.

Comment: An IV is a random number that guarantees the encrypted text is unique.

Comment: OK, yes, I can see that now. What I was trying to say is that a normal session cookie doesn't contain a "value" of any kind. It's just [a token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID). So, what "value" are you encrypting and storing in the cookie? Also, why are you creating your own session handling system? What special needs to you have?

Comment: My question is not about possible workarounds or solutions but rather about encryption. Do I need to sign the IV in the cookie with another key, or this does not add any additional security benefits? it's about having a cookie value that cannot be tampered.

Comment: Sorry, I now see that you intend to store the user id in the cookie. That is not a good idea. Normal sessions work like this: You [generate an unique random token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string). You store this token with the user in the database and you store it in the session cookie. Then when the session needs to be restarted you compare the cookie against the token you've stored for the user. This way the cookie never contains the user id, no encryption is needed, and you don't need to worry about alterations of the cookie.

Comment: As a side note, if the encrypted data contains `::`, your code won't work.

Comment: Regarding session management. If a cookies contains random data, and that data mapped to a user only server side, then no encryption is needed. But let's say I want to keep some user data in the cookie (don't ask why, pure theoretically).

Comment: @kiko-software, btw how would you manage multiple session IDs in one database? If a user logs in from multiple devices, one must either store multiple session IDs in the database or share session IDs between sessions, which in my opinion, does not make it a session ID anymore

Comment: Normally you would generate a new token every time an user logs in. So when the user starts using a second device, and logs in, the token will change. This means the user is automatically logged out of the first device, since the old token is no longer valid.

Comment: Or you could store a secure id in a db, store that in a cookie and then validate these. And if this is encrypted the cookie will be different for each session because of the IV. This method allows users to be logged in from multiple devices. And, once the secure ID changes, the user will be automatically signed out from all sessions

Comment: Having a single user sign in from multiple devices can be a headache for several reasons. However, under certain circumstances it can be useful. In that case I would allow a single user to store multiple tokens. I understand what you're trying to say: With your encryption method you can use a single secure session id for multiple devices. Yes, I can see how that could work. Just remember: it is also easy to revoke multiple tokens.

Comment: And that brings us back to the initial question: Should the IV be stored in the cookie, signed with a hash, or is this additional layer useless?

Comment: I would regard the IV as somewhat your secret. I would not hand it over to a potential hacker in a cookie. Doing that basically makes it useless. Always assume that a hacker knows what the data in your cookie represents and can use that knowledge against you. [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is usually a bad idea and might create a false sense of safety. Use algorithms that are [secure by design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_by_design). This is why we have standard methods of doing certain things.

Comment: The IV is not a secret, the key is. The IV is typically prepended to the cipher. Cipher modes like GCM have a built-in MAC that is used to detect tampering of data, so no need for an extra hash.