# protecting content in jar file

Tags: java-me, mobile, jar, protected

I made a mobile application. On extracting the jar file, the resource files are visible ( text files and image files ). Is there someway to protect the content files?  I am not worried about the reverse engineering of the bytecode. I need to protect the content. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only 100% secure way to protect the resource files is to omit them from the jar.

Seriously.

If your application needs to use your resources, you *could* store the resources encrypted, and then decrypt them as needed. But in the end, **you're still handing the data to an untrusted entity.**

Comment: thanx for the reply :) i m using base64encoding technique for the encryption, is there some other more efficient method for encryption?

Comment: That's encoding, not encryption. **Anyone** can decode base64-encoded information. [Security by obscurity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533965/why-is-security-through-obscurity-a-bad-idea) is not security at all.