# Django - How to change the location of admin static files?

Tags: python, django, admin, collectstatic

I recently discovered that it's quite easy to check if a site is running on Django as its not possible to change the location of DJANGO Admin styles located at `/static/admin/css/base.css`
The only thing I can change at the path shown above is `/static` as I set :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

at `settings.py`

Is there any way that I can change the path behind `/static` ?

Would be great If I could hide the framework that I'm using for my website.

Comment: *Security through obscurity* is nearly always a bad idea https://stackoverflow.com/q/533965/67579

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If you are about "Sooner or later, the problems will be discovered" you are probaly right but what if im about to play on time?

Comment: but imagine that you change the static url, then a web crawler will likely find the `admin` page easily, and thus also the static css file, since that is "imported" in that page. It thus does not make much sense. Furthermore there are a lot of ways to tell it is a Django server, for example the template engine often renders a lot of blank lines due to how the loops unwind, or for example the typical cookies set for language selection. For most web servers, it is quite easy to find out what the software is that runs behind it.

Comment: you can try to move the css to another place and overwrite the template base_site.html. Is only a idea