# PHP: how to hide $GET_id from the link?

Tags: php

I want to hide the id from the link to be something like [www.example.com/edit?DashboardId=14c140fc-b269-46e3-9649-d2c374d9d1e1&SelectedId=db250226-ad35-40ac-a321-1eedbe3460fc](http://www.example.com/edit?DashboardId=14c140fc-b269-46e3-9649-d2c374d9d1e1&SelectedId=db250226-ad35-40ac-a321-1eedbe3460fc)

My current link is [www.example.com/edit?DashboardId=14](http://www.example.com/edit?DashboardId=14)

Comment: you cannot hide but you can encrypt it

Comment: if you want to keep it secrete the please use POST Request instead of get Request

Comment: if you want to hide u can use POST Request or SESSION instead of get

Comment: If you want to have user friendly URL, use URL rewriting where you map `Dashboardid=14` into `14c140fc-b269-46e3-9649-d2c374d9d1e1`

Comment: [Is obfuscation actually security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533965/why-is-security-through-obscurity-a-bad-idea) - If you are trying to "hide" certain stuff, then it's worthwhile to rethink your strategy!

Comment: the reason am using get is that i still want to use the id in the form to perform some operations

Comment: @KayesFahim Using POST doesn't keep the values _secret_, users can use the browsers DevConsole/Network tab to see which values have been sent.

Comment: You could look into having a UUID on each record, so that is used in any links produced.

Comment: Why do you think you need to hide the ID?

Comment: You're describing a UUID on each record (as a column) to use as an alternate reference. Note, switching to a UUID will make it harder to guess than a number, but obscurity only provides so much security (as opposed to checking permissions and access for each item).