# Decrypt file so that my code is able to run JS

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

Relatively new here, I encrypted all my files except the main.js file. Now I wan to decrypt the files before running my main.js. If i run main.js now it doesnt work due to the encrypted files. Is this a valid way?

Current Idea

1. Write decryption code before running main.js

Code below is for decryption but it produces another file, I wan it so that it just read and let me access the files. Hopefully I explained clearly :(

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const path = require('path');

const rootDirectory = './';
const encryptedDirectory = path.join(rootDirectory, 'Encrypted Files');
const decryptedDirectory = path.join(rootDirectory, 'Decrypted Files');
const encryptionKeyPath = path.join(rootDirectory, 'encryptionKey.txt');

// Load the encryption key from file
const encryptionKey = fs.readFileSync(encryptionKeyPath);

// Decrypt and save each file in the encrypted directory
decryptDirectory(encryptedDirectory);

function decryptDirectory(directory) {
  // Read the files and subdirectories in the directory
  const entries = fs.readdirSync(directory, { withFileTypes: true });

  // Iterate over the entries
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    const entryPath = path.join(directory, entry.name);

    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      // Decrypt files in subdirectories recursively
      decryptDirectory(entryPath);
    } else {
      // Read the encrypted file
      const encryptedBuffer = fs.readFileSync(entryPath);

      // Extract the IV from the encrypted file
      const iv = encryptedBuffer.slice(0, 16); // Assuming the IV is stored at the beginning

      // The rest of the buffer is the encrypted data
      const encryptedData = encryptedBuffer.slice(16);

      // Create a decipher with AES algorithm, the encryption key, and the IV
      const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encryptionKey, iv);

      // Decrypt the file
      const decryptedBuffer = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(encryptedData), decipher.final()]);

      // Create the corresponding output directory structure
      const relativePath = path.relative(encryptedDirectory, entryPath);
      const outputPath = path.join(decryptedDirectory, relativePath);

      // Ensure the output directory exists
      fs.mkdirSync(path.dirname(outputPath), { recursive: true });

      // Save the decrypted file
      fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, decryptedBuffer);
    }
  });
}
```

Tried running decryption code before running main.js , basically the decryption is above main.js

Comment: are you encrypting *code* files?

Comment: yes, i encrypted the code files, the idea is to decrypt the other files before running main.js since it have routes to the encrypted files. So my plan is to decrypt it so that it able to access the content. Not sure if this is a good practice hence seeking out help :3

Comment: Why did you encrypt your javascript files in the first place?

Comment: for security purpose :D

Comment: [Why is security through obscurity a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533965/why-is-security-through-obscurity-a-bad-idea) - You've tagged this with JavaScript, meaning the files are publicly available thus the decryption method will be clearly visible for anyone who does an effort

Comment: yea true but as they don't know the key, it is still harder to break rather than exposing all the data without any encryption I guess.

Comment: How wouldn't they know the key? Your `main.js` has or needs to know the key in order to decrypt.

Comment: hmmm in that case what is a good practise to protect the code when its distributed to the public