# How to get deobfuscation file in React Native app with obfuscator-io-metro-plugin

Tags: react-native, obfuscation, deobfuscation

We are developing a mobile app with React Native/Expo and our partner requires us to use some kind of code obfuscation. The only viable solution we found was [obfuscator-io-metro-plugin](https:////https://www.npmjs.com/package/obfuscator-io-metro-plugin)
Now the app stores say the deobfuscation file is missing which will make debuggin crashes harder. Is it possible to create this deobfuscation file with this plugin and if so, then how? I couldn't find anything on it in plugin docs.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/219346/does-code-obfuscation-give-any-measurable-security-benefit - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533965/why-is-security-through-obscurity-a-bad-idea

Comment: So, how does this answer any of my problems? The question was not if it is useful or not. And that post you linked actually didn't give any real answer to that question either.

Comment: If it was an answer, I would posted those as an answer. It's head-ups for you and your partner. Obfuscating code is just as good as using no security at all. If your question is actually the following "*is it possible to create this deobfuscation file?*". There is no need for this file to be created, this is just the non-obfuscated code, which you've obfuscated. Ofc. it will make debugging possible errors/exceptions harder, as the code is obfuscated.

Comment: If actually errors/exceptions occur, you guys will have to spent more resources/time (a.ka. money) in just pinpointing the problem, before you could even start to fix the errors/exceptions and then afterwards you would need to re-obfuscate the fixed code again. Consider if it's actually worth the effort (and money) going on this path

Comment: Unfortunately, it is required of us and can't be avoided. The requirement comes from a top 50 fortune 500 company and is pretty much non -negotiable...    Ps. Sorry if I sounded a bit snappy there, but I do realize the futility of obfuscating code.

Comment: No worries, I did some googling. Perhaps the following resources are useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84b7tir_BjE